# NodeJS Routing - Post Login - with JWT and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, routes, jwt

I have seen more examples than I can count of how to build an NodeJS api with JWT, however, I have not seen anything on how to use the token when navigating your page via the routing.

I have the JTW authentication working. I am returning a token to the user and saving it in cookies and local memory. The part I am stuck on is the proper way to use that token when trying to navigate to other URIs on my site.

For example, when the user goes to my main page (mySite.com), they will be presented with an awesome picture and a login form. They successfully log in, get the token, but now the site needs to forward to mySite.com/**home**. If I am not using any fancy tools, just jQuery GET/PUT/POST/etc, how is this done?

Currently I make the original PUT, sending the username and password, which if successful it calls a jQuery callback that takes the returned token and saves it in the cookies and then makes a GET call (with the token) to get the "/home" page html. The GET returns the HTML which I then call $('body').html(response) to render that HTML. The only problem is that I am still at the URL mySite.com, not mySite.com/home.

If I try to do a redirect in the backend of the frontend, my JWT blocks it because I am not passing the token with it. Is there a way to do a redirect with a JWT or something?

Comment: You may want to deal with the browser's history API.

Comment: No clue what you mean here @31piy. What does the browser's history have to do with routing through your website?

Comment: Almost all the routing frameworks on JS deal with history API to facilitate SPA. You may want to [have a look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) at it.